# Pros and cons of double majoring vs a Master's

Tags: masters, undergraduate, major

I've looked into double majoring at my university and it seems that, as is apparently common, it's very likely that if I go down this track I will not graduate in 4 years, but probably in 5 or 6. This makes me wonder: what are the implications for a career in either industry or academia of a double major, as opposed to doing a single major, graduating in 4 years, and using the next 2 years to study for a Master's degree instead?

Comment: It's hard to say much without knowing what the two fields are and what your aspirations are, but in general I would find a master's more impressive than a double major.  However, if you wanted to go into arts administration, a double major in the right fields could look very good.  There might be other exceptions as well.

Comment: As other people have suggested, you will need to give more information to get a useful answer as it can be case - and country dependant.  _In general_, I wouldn't advocate a double major in the US if it will push back your graduation date.  If you are looking towards academia, keep on track for the standard graduation date, spend your extra time/summers with undergraduate research, then apply to direct PhD programs or research-based Masters.

Comment: I have found my own double-major extremely helpful to me (computer information systems and psychology) - but if it would have required more than 1-2 extra semesters I would not have done it, and there's a good chance you shouldn't either. In most setups you can take your electives in your second major, some classes double count (I used classes in both of my majors to also fulfill general education requirements), etc. Spending 2 years just for a second major sounds way, way past the value you could get out, save for one situation: you changed your mind near the end and need the new major.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general (and from the perspective of academia) I would say many *undergraduate students* overrate the value of double majoring and misunderstand its importance. Having two majors does not make you an expert in two fields. Moreover, depending on the fields in question, it doesn't aid your ability to go onto graduate school.

*All things being equal* a masters degree is

- more useful for employment (I've never seen a job that explicitly requires a dual major but some jobs list a masters degree as a qualification).
- a better indication of academic ability in a field
- a more impressive credential than a dual major.

But there are several things that could make things unequal.

First, there are cases where showing a background in two fields is valuable, because a job bridges two skill sets. As aparente001 suggests in a comment, majoring in administration and art might better show an aptitude for managing a gallery than just one or the other. (Another example: a patent attorney often has a degree in science).

Second, there are cases where a graduate field requires knowledge (or some competency) in multiple underlying fields such as materials science (chemistry and engineering).

Third, if for personal reasons you desperately want to study both because you believe you will never be able to study the other after you go to graduate school, then it might be worth it to someone to spend 1 or 2 years to do that.

While there may be other special circumstances that make sense of it, I would say it's unlikely that the value towards academia of getting a second major is worth two years that could have been spent on an MA.

(For the record, I did two majors and don't regret it -- but I finished both in the usual 4 years).